# extjs not rendering anything in iframe in internet explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, extjs, internet-explorer-9

My iframe content developed using extjs shows perfectly in Chrome, firefox and safari.

It is not rendering anything in iframe in internet explorer. I made sure that there are no warnings in sencha cmd. no extra commas, I looked at console in i.e. 9, it doesn't show any errors.

*This is the div that renders mywebpage in iframe.*

```
<div aria-hidden="false" aria-expanded="true" style="display: block;" role="tabpanel" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" id="cmeTabs-app0"><iframe id="app0-Frame" class="ifrmclass" src="mywebpage.html" style="height: 876px;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">$('#app0-Frame').height($(window).height() - 110)</script>
```

*and this is the mywebpage.html content.*

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyWebPage</title>
    <!-- Importing styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-theme-gray/build/resources/ext-theme-gray-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext/ext-all-debug.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="myGrid" class="myGridContainer">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The header has been developed by other team in jquery and our webpage has to go inside an iframe and we are using extjs to develop that iframe content.

Comment: How do you start your app? the html page above has only bootstrap.js, no app.js.

Comment: Currently the app is in dev. I am doing a sencha app watch and able to start the app.

Comment: Well, I mean where is the application code? Normally you have link to `app.js` script in `index.html` but I don't see it above.

Comment: I have tried by linking app.js '<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>' when you mentioned it, it didn't work either.